# IOS - Parsing objects from Firebase - Code running before download is completed

Tags: swift, parsing, asynchronous, firebase, completionhandler

I am trying to parse data from Firebase into an array of objects, and upon completion display the text from the first object in the array. However, I can't work out/find a solution to stop the code continuing before the download is complete. So it proceeds to update the user's completion to true, without displaying the text. This is the function as is, the downloading and appending to array works fine, but it skips to displayNextInSeries() before it's finished...

```
    func parseSeries (ref: String)  {
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("library").child("series").child(ref).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  { (snapshot)  in

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            for snap in snapshot {

                print(snap)

                if let pushSeriesDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    let key = snap.key
                    let push = PUSH_SERIES(pushKey: key, pushSeriesData: pushSeriesDict)
                    self.seriesArray.append(push)

                }
            }
        }
    })

    print("\(ref) Series Count: \(self.seriesArray.count)")
    displayNextInSeries()

}
```

The display next in series function sees the seriesArray.count = 0, so it doesn't update the texLbl:

```
   func displayNextInSeries() {

    if seriesProgress < seriesArray.count {

        animateProgress(current: seriesProgress, total: seriesArray.count)

        currentPUSH_SERIES = seriesArray[seriesProgress]
        currentPUSH_SERIES.text = personaliseText(text: currentPUSH_SERIES.text)

        textLbl.animateUpdate(currentPUSH_SERIES.text, oldText: previousText)
        titleLbl.text = "\(currentPUSH_SERIES.title!)"
        previousText = currentPUSH_SERIES.text

        seriesProgress += 1

    } else {

        animateProgress(current: sessionProgress, total: sessionTarget)

        titleLbl.text = ""
        greetingPush()
        seriesPlay = false
        seriesProgress = 0

        user.updateProgress(seriesName)
        print(user.progress)


    }

}
```

I may be doing something fundamentally wrong here. Your help is much needed and much appreciated! Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `observeSingleOfEvent` is an asynchronous call, calling the function inside the completionBlock will solve it,The problem is that your print function is being called even before `observeSingleOfEvent` is finished downloading data :-

```
func parseSeries (ref: String)  {
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("library").child("series").child(ref).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  { (snapshot)  in

    if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

        for snap in snapshot {

            print(snap)

            if let pushSeriesDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                let key = snap.key
                let push = PUSH_SERIES(pushKey: key, pushSeriesData: pushSeriesDict)
                self.seriesArray.append(push)
                print("\(ref) Series Count: \(self.seriesArray.count)")
                displayNextInSeries()
            }
        }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Accept this as answer if it solved your issue :)Happy coding

Comment: Thanks D. I just needed to move the displayNext function. Thanks for the answer :)